# How do I use the crypt function in a where in a laravel query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, crypt

I need to use the crypt function in a query in laravel. It is a system of saving passwords, and the user and password are encrypted by Crypt::encrypt, I would like to know if it is possible to decrypt in a query to do the search per user too, instead of just the password name.

```
    $passwords = Password::query()
        ->when($filter_category, function($q) use ($filter_category){
            $q->where('category_id', $filter_category);
        })
        ->when($filter_search, function($q) use ($filter_search){
            $q->whereHas('category', function ($q) use ($filter_search){
                $q->where('category_name', 'LIKE', "%$filter_search%");
            });
            $q->orWhere('password_name', 'LIKE', "%$filter_search%");
        })
        ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
        ->paginate(10)
        ->through(function ($query) {
            if ($query->password_login) {
                $query->password_login = $this->formatLogin(Crypt::decrypt($query->password_login));
            }
            return $query;
        });
```

This is the current query, the through() is used for decrypt and show formated, with "exam****@gmail.com" in table, but this dont alter for where work.

I tried to use what was presented earlier. I need to decrypt the login before where to be able to later comcant it for the search.

Comment: Maybe better to make a search with encrypted values since they are in the database? Something like `->where('password_login', Crypt::encrypt($request->password_login)`

Comment: @Lothric dont work, this generate different strings because the serialization